# lateinit property appContext has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

when I build my application under Android Studio, I don't have an error on the build process but when I load the apk on firebase, I have this error

> Schwerer Ausnahmefehler
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver example.com.App.tasks.AlarmReceiver: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property appContext has not been initialized

here is my declaration and initialization for my lateninit.

on my activity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    )

    appContext = applicationContext
 }

companion object {
    lateinit  var appContext: Context
}
```

and i implement the function WriteBtn_ in another class AlarmReceiver

```
fun WriteBtn_(finename: String, mystring : String) {

    val fileout = appContext.openFileOutput(finename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val outputWriter = OutputStreamWriter(fileout)

    try {
        outputWriter.write(mystring)
        outputWriter.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        outputWriter.close()
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

thank you

Comment: i don't see the point in your companion object here, you're doing `appContext = applicationContext` and you're obviously getting `applicationContext` from somewhere, so why not use that in your `AlarmReceiver` class

Comment: because i need the appContext  global

Answer (score 2):

func life circle is error, you need make sure the `WriteBtn_` run after activity-`onCreate`

suggest use `MyApplication.appContext`

Answer (score 0):

Your initialisation of that `appContext` property relies on your `Activity` being created before anything tries to access the app context. And that's not happening, your `AlarmReceiver` is getting to it first and trying to read it before the value has been set

Like Jie Xu says, it's probably better to initialise it early by [creating a custom `Application` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) and making it accessible from there

Comment: cool thank´s it´s work by creating a custom Application class and initialise it